# Optimizing apply function output

Tags: r

I have the following function:

```
library (reshape)
phenotype <- rnorm (100)
data <- matrix(rnorm(1000), nrow = 10, ncol=100)

spearman.p <-
             reshape(
                     melt(
                          apply(data, 1, function(y){
                                        cor.test(y,phenotype,method="spearman")
                                                    }[c("p.value", "estimate")]
                               )
                          ), timevar="L2", idvar="L1", direction="wide"
                       )
```

that I would like to know if there is a more efficent way of getting out the p.value and estimate from a "apply"ed cor.test

Can anyone provide some suggestions?

Comment: Suggestion #1: please provide some sample data.

Comment: +1, gulity! - example data added...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be more compact and delivers the p.values from the duplicated data. Is that what you wanted?:

```
 dtt <- do.call(rbind, apply(data, 1, function(y){
                            cor.test(y,phenotype,method="spearman")
                                  }[c("p.value", "estimate")]
                                 ) )
  dtt
 ###      p.value   estimate 
     [1,] 0.2305644 0.1208641
     [2,] 0.2305644 0.1208641
     [3,] 0.2305644 0.1208641
     [4,] 0.2305644 0.1208641
     [5,] 0.2305644 0.1208641
     [6,] 0.2305644 0.1208641
     [7,] 0.2305644 0.1208641
     [8,] 0.2305644 0.1208641
     [9,] 0.2305644 0.1208641
    [10,] 0.2305644 0.1208641
```

Edit: If you are looking for speed and/or the possibility of easily transporting to parallel-oriented platforms then add this to the list of candidates:

```
 pmtx <- matrix(NA, nrow=nrow(data), ncol=2)
 for( i in 1:nrow(data) ) {
  pmtx[i, 1:2 ] <- unlist(cor.test(data[i, ], 
                                   phenotype, 
                                   method="spearman")[c("p.value", "estimate")] ) }
 pmtx
```

Comment: I think this is close to what I want and the pvalues are the same due to the structure of the example data.  My real data is well, real and not so structured and different p.values are obtained for each row but your results are correct (edited example data above as well).  Speed is crucial, as I need to run several hundred thousand of these in parallel via SGE submission. I think this is cleaner than my reshape/melt mess.  Will test speed and let you know how it fares. Thanks for suggestion!

Comment: For loops are often faster than the *apply methods. Lower overhead.

Comment: Your solution was 3X faster than what I had!  Thanks!  (30 seconds verses 90 seconds)

Answer (score 3):

This is the best I can come up with at the moment.

```
FUN <- function(y) {
  test <- cor.test(y,phenotype,method="spearman")
  out <- unlist(test[c("p.value", "estimate")])
}
t(apply(data, 1, FUN))
```

Comment: Will test speed on some real data and let you know how it fares. Thanks for suggestion!

Comment: My only regret is that I have only one green check to give.  Your solution was also 3X faster than what I had!  Thanks!  (30 seconds verses 90 seconds)